# Interface Builder Won't let me set view outlet connection

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The view outlet on my nib file is not set so I'm trying to set it but when I drag from the outlet to the view, the view won't highlight (as you can see in the screenshot. So when I let go, nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set Custom class of file owner inside of the .xib file first.  Then the interface builder will let you set the reference outlet of the view.